# Access $_SESSION variable from wp page in a non-wp page

Tags: php, wordpress

My wordpress blog requires a username & password. On the first wp page I've placed:

```
<?php 
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $name = $current_user->user_firstname . ' '.$current_user->user_lastname;
  $_SESSION['memberName'] = $name;
  echo '<h2>Welcome ' . $name . '</h2>';
?>
```

As expected, "Welcome" appears along with the user's name. I have a Custom menu that transfers the user to a NON-WP page, with the initial lines:

```
<?php 
  session_start(); 
  $name = $_SESSION['memberName'];
?>
```

BUT, after linking to this non-wp page, $name is blank. How can I transfer the !name in a session?

Comment: are both on the same domain?

Answer (score 0):

Make it a WP page loading WP like this:

```
require_once('PathToBlogRoot/wp-load.php');
```

I think that would be the easiest way to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

If it's on the same domain you can add it to a cookie, like so

```
<?php 
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $name = $current_user->user_firstname . ' '.$current_user->user_lastname;
  setcookie("guest_name", $name);

  echo '<h2>Welcome ' . $name . '</h2>';
?>
```

And then on the NON WP page  you have something like

```
<?php echo $_COOKIE('guest_name'); ?>
```

If you are redirecting them to another domain it's best that you put the username in the GET parameters. Like when you do the redirect to the new page you just add the username

```
<?php


   $name = $current_user->user_firstname . ' '.$current_user->user_lastname;
   header( 'Location: http://your_non_wp_page/index.php?username='.$name ) ;

?>
```

and then on that page you just do

`<?php echo $_GET['username']; ?>`

But cookie would be more persistent.

Comment: The non-wp page IS in the same domain. I got this error message in my WP page. I also had errors in the non-wp page, but they were probably related to the first error. 
Warning: Cannot modify header information – headers already sent by (output started at ...../wordpress/wp-content/themes/twentyten/header.php:12)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [**WP Sessions Plugin**](http://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-sessions-plugin-with-database/3405722?WT.ac=new_item&WT.seg_1=new_item&WT.z_author=screets). It creates session for you and when user change his profile data, this plugin also update his session data. At the same time, if user logged out, then the plugin removes his session data from database.

Some examples:

You can **add** session data like this:

```
// One value
$session->set_userdata( 'username', 'john' );

// Passing array
$array = array(
    'username' => 'john',
    'email'    => 'john@gmail.com'
);

$session->set_userdata( $array );
```

To **retrieve** session data:

```
$session->userdata( 'username' );
```

To **get all** session data:

```
$session->all_userdata(); // returns array
```

To **remove** one item from session:

```
$session->unset_userdata( 'username' );
```

To **remove more items** from session:

```
$array = array(
    'username' => '',
    'email'    => ''
);
$session->unset_userdata( $array );
```

You can also use **Flashdata** which is session data that will only be available for the next server request, are then automatically cleared. These can be very useful when you use them for *informational* or *status messages* (e.g. “Product has been deleted”).

```
// Add Flashdata
$session->set_flashdata( 'item', 'value' );

// Retrieve Flashdata
$session->flashdata( 'item' );

// Preserving flashdata 
// (if you need to preserve flashdata through an additional request, 
// you can use this function):
$session->keep_flashdata( 'item' );
```

To destroy session:

```
$session->sess_destroy();
```

The plugin also supports **shortcodes**. You can print any session data on your posts or pages:

```
[session key="username"]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

While Vladimir gets some credit - since he pointed me to setcookie() - a major problem is the need to place setcookie before the html line in a file; not so easy in WP. One of the few places to do this in WordPress is in the functions.php file; e.g.:

```
function set_user_cookie() {
  global $current_user;
  get_currentuserinfo();
  $name = $current_user->user_firstname . ' '.$current_user->user_lastname;
  setcookie('member_name', $name,time()+60*60*20,'/');   // 20 hours
}
add_action( 'init', 'set_user_cookie');
```

Then it was easy to retrieve the cookie info in my non-wp page with